# wix installer upgrade dialog not displaying, how to prepare?

Tags: windows, wix, upgrade

I have installed msi on client location. Now i need to provide upgrade. When i prepare new msi with new version it is saying product is already installed. How to upgrade product.

```
Existing product msi(wix) info:
ProductVersion      :   0.0.0.1
PackageCode {B3B7B3A9-AF58-41C0-B3BD-F5ED1B5DE914}
UpgradeCode {63B4B483-1851-4F32-BEFA-E7D73C4CE0DE}
ProductCode {1F3EFF43-C480-4956-B076-76437B6313E6}
```

My wix looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?define ProductVersion = "0.0.0.2"?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "63b4b483-1851-4f32-befa-e7d73c4ce0de"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Calculator" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="ABCD" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
      <!-- Detect older product versions -->
      <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="yes" Minimum="0.0.0.1" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" />
      <!-- Detect newer product versions -->
      <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" IncludeMinimum="no" Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED" />
    </Upgrade>
    <!-- Exits successfully in the case newer version are already installed -->
    <CustomActionRef Id="WixExitEarlyWithSuccess" />

and continues....
```

Whats wrong in my code.  I would like to get upgrade option from this.

Answer (score 0):

It will say the product is already installed if either the ProductCode or the PackageCode of the new MSI is the same as the previous one. It's not clear to me from your post if they have both changed or not.

Also, you won't get an upgrade unless you change something in the first three fields of the ProductVersion. This is the behavior of Windows Installer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: existing product info is available in the question, based on that what should i modify in the provided wix xml in order to install updated version of new product? (i did some changes, after that it is installing product. But previous version and new version stays.)I want to update the product

Comment: Have you scheduled a RemoveExistingProducts? Try the WiX majorupgrade tag. Plus a per -user will not upgrade a per system (and vice versa).